# How to compose in this situation

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

```js
var articles = [
  {
    title: 'Everything Sucks',
    author: { name: 'Debbie Downer' }
  },
  {
    title: 'If You Please',
    author: { name: 'Caspar Milquetoast' }
  }
];

var names = _.map(_.compose(_.get('name'), _.get('author'))) 
// returning ['Debbie Downer', 'Caspar Milquetoast']
```

Now based on the above given `articles` and function `names`, make a boolean function that says whether a given person wrote any of the articles.

```js
isAuthor('New Guy', articles) //false
isAuthor('Debbie Downer', articles)//true
```

My attempts on below

```js
var isAuthor = (name, articles) => {
    return _.compose(_.contains(name), names(articles))
};
```

However it's failing on `jsbin` with error below. Perhaps someone can try to explain what goes wrong with my attempt so that I can learn from mistake

> Uncaught expected false to equal function(n,t){return r.apply(this,arguments)}

Comment: @MaheerAli: I'm looking for answer that can explain the situation i'm facing, and answer in ramda only, thanks!

Comment: Are you using Ramda, lodash, or underscore?

Comment: @AaditMShah: It's `Ramda`, I've tagged it in the question

Comment: Sure, but you're using `_` instead of `R`, and [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) is a lodash function. It's not a Ramda function. If you say that you're using a particular library make sure that the code in your question actually uses that library.

Comment: @AaditMShah: In the very early days of Ramda, `prop` was named (or aliased?) as `get`.  There are probably some very old Ramda resources which mention `get`.  But it hasn't been in the library for some years.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Found the get method from https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/composeK.js but didn't noticed it's been deprecated

Comment: @Isaac: That's simply used for an example: it gives a total function version of `prop`, but one which returns a `Maybe`.  It's not an actual Ramda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose returns a function, so you need to pass `articles` to that function. Compose will pass the `articles` to `getNames`, and will pass the result of `getNames` to `contains(name)` (which also returns a function) that will handle the author names, and return the boolean `result`:

```js
const { map, path, compose, contains } = R

const getNames = map(path(['author', 'name']))

const isAuthor = (name) => compose(
  contains(name),
  getNames
)

const articles = [{"title":"Everything Sucks","author":{"name":"Debbie Downer"}},{"title":"If You Please","author":{"name":"Caspar Milquetoast"}}]

console.log(isAuthor('New Guy')(articles)) //false
console.log(isAuthor('Debbie Downer')(articles)) //true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```